# CSS - fitting 100% of parent's space?

Tags: html, css, position

I want to create a span inside of a link (a href) tag, I want the span to take 100% width & height of the parent link element. I've been trying with position relative/absolute but nothings works.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dDZRj/

Comment: What exactly is your desired result? If you want what I think you want, you'll have to set things up a bit differently, but without a clear picture of what you're going for it'll be mere speculation.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks I want to achieve spans that will affect parent link a element and resize it. So a's border will look like an outline for spans border, I want no space between spans and links border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this it?

http://jsfiddle.net/dDZRj/11/

```
body {
    margin: 25px;
}

.button {
    margin: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none
}   

.button span {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 100%;
}

.big {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: @thirtydot you are the MAN! It doesn't work well on my website trough, but I'm going to figure that out, probably something overrides .button or so. By they way what did you do to force it to work? inline-block is all I missed?

Comment: Almost. All I added was `display: inline-block`, and I changed the padding on `.button` to `padding: 10px 0`, which means top and bottom `10px`, left and right `0`. What's wrong with it on your site?

Comment: @thirtydot, holy cow, that's a tough one, I'm pasting exact button code (CSS/HTML) to JsFiddle and it looks great, but on my website it looks good only width font-size: 1em, spans height is too low for font sizes smaller than 1em and they "go outside" of the a element if font size is bigger than 1em. The worst thing is Firebug shows nothing unusual. I was thinking about line-height, but that's not the point.

Comment: @thirtydot I will past a link here within a minute.

Comment: Ah, display: inline-block; +1

Comment: Try on `.button` `line-height: normal`. Or, try putting the border on `.button` instead of on `.button span`.

Comment: @thirtydot, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/SbcA3/

Comment: I'll figure it out sooner or later, I want to use two borders at once and that's the problem. line-height doesn't help. And nothing, at least directly changes look of these elements in my case. At least FireBug shows only .button & .button span & .button big.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/dDZRj/4/

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 25px;
}

.button {
    margin: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #999;  
}   

.button span {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.big {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<a href="#" class="button"><span>Click me!</span></a>

<a href="#" class="button big">
    <span>Click me!</span></a>

<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Click me!</span>
</a>
```

Comment: @Loktar, aff, it seems so easy, but is not. There's a whitespace after the last span in your example :(

Comment: @Loktar thanks to @Rudu your example works perfectly! Thank you both! :)

Comment: Also I think this is world the other way around, here the `a` tags adjust their size to the `span` inside. I think the question is the other way around. The `span` should adjust to the size of the `a`. Try giving a `a` `display:inline-block` and a fixed width bigger than the `span` and the `span` will not adjust.

Comment: @Loktar, wait, that's totally wrong, I NEED PADDINGS. BADLY :( I've just noticed that your code works because there are no paddings :/

Comment: @anonymous: I thought you wanted the `padding` on the button/link? I have a solution which allows for the `padding`, but I'm not going to post it if this is already what you want. Edit: Lol.

Comment: @thirtydot of course I wanted paddings, buttons without them look lame! ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox at least you need to change our source to:

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Click me!</span></a>

<a href="#" class="button big">
    <span>Click me!</span></a>

<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Click me!</span></a>
```

But otherwise @Loktar's CSS works great :)

Comment: I hate hate hate this code whitespace html glitch. Thank you!

Comment: @anonymous it's not a glitch, there is in fact a whitespace character between the `</span>` and `</a>`, namely the tab that you used to indent the next line before the `</a>`. `a` and `span` are inline elements which take whitespace between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the span:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: doesn't look good: http://jsfiddle.net/dDZRj/3/ :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after, the `a` can have any size in width and the `span` will adjust its size to match. Oh and there is padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/dDZRj/12/